# Android 5.0+ camera2 api real fullscreen

Tags: android, overlay, fullscreen, android-camera2

I'm trying to make fullscreen camera preview (like full HD) but I cannot set proper resolution on this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Am I missing something in styles? Acutally I'm using "theme.appcompat.light.noactionbar" and hardcoded 1920x1080 camera resolution but still there are some bars on screen and I can't achieve fullscreen.

Also can I display some overlay on texture view after camera preview will be set?

Comment: I added `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` to onCreate method and now i have strange bar on bottom of the landscape screen and still buttons on the right (back, menu, apps) appears.

Answer (score 0):

I just used immersive mode from android 4.4+ for fullscreen :)
Also for overlay i used texture view + open gl es 2.0 support.